# Is the function $f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x \sqrt{|y|} }{2x^2+|y|} &(x,y) \neq (0,0) \\0&(x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}$ continuous at $R^2$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have the following function
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x \sqrt{|y|} }{2x^2+|y|} &(x,y) \neq (0,0) \\0&(x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}$$

Is this function continuous at $R^2$?
I've tried to prove that it is not continuous at $(0,0)$, but did not succeed.
Would much appreciate help.
Thank you!

Comment: ... continuous *in* $\mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function to be continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it is not enough that the partial limits in the axes $x=0$ and $y=0$ exist and be equal, as I'm supposing you tried (it's a common mistake). You need to guarantee that this limit is the same for all paths going through the point.

For instance, in this case, the axes limits are both equal:
$$
\lim\limits_{y\to0}f(0,y)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x,0)=0.
$$
But you can also take the parabola $y=x^2$ and check that
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to0^\pm}f(x,x^2)=\lim\limits_{x->0^\pm}\frac{x|x|}{3x^2}=\pm\frac{1}{3}.
$$
Since they are different, the limit doesn't exist.

A little visualization goes a long way, I recommend Mathematica if you have access to a license.
[image: visualization]

Answer (score 1):

The limit at the origin along the positive arm of the path $y=x^2$ is $\dfrac{1}{3}$. So it is not continuous there.

$$ \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x\sqrt{x^2}}{2x^2+x^2}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{|x|}{3x}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: How is it $1/3$?

Comment: OK, I will fill that in. Give me a minute.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

We have that by $x=u$ and $|y|=v^2$
$$ \frac{x \sqrt{|y|} }{2x^2+|y|} = \frac{u v }{2u^2+v^2}=\frac{\cos \theta \sin \theta}{\cos^2\theta + 1}$$

therefore the limit doesn't exists at $(0,0)$.

Comment: If I understand right, what you wrote means that the function indeed is continuous in $R^2$?

Comment: @Dave Sorry I made a mistake with $x^2\le |x|$. Limit at $(0,0)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm surprised :) Can I ask you once again to explain it without polar coordinates?

Comment: @Dave John Wayland Bales has already shown that for $y=x^2$ limit is $\frac13$. Now it suffices to observe that for $x=0$ limit is equal to zero.

Comment: Can you explain your second sentence? Did not understand it well.

Comment: @user Actually, they are given that $f(0,0)=0$ so no other limit is necessary.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes you are right of course! And we can't make it continuous chosing any other value.

Comment: @Dave What I mean is simply that $$\lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)}f(0,y)=\lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)}0=0$$ Anway as noticed by John Wayland Bales the first result suffices in this case.

Comment: Understood. Thank you both.